# Finding Meanings of English Names

Tags: names, surnames, nicknames

In Sinhala the name Suminda means calm disposition from the words Samya (calm) + Indu (faculties).

In the case of English, how does one understand the meaning of names? E.g. names like Ann, Tom, Dick, Harry, Edward, etc. does not have an easily identifiable meaning or are related to any identifiable English words.

Comment: Try https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198610601.001.0001/acref-9780198610601

Comment: Names traditionally used in Britain come from many sources. Tom, Dick and Harry are nicknames for Thomas (a Biblical name), Richard (of German origin) and Henry (or Harold). Some names, such as Patience, Rose or Violet, have obvious meanings. There are reference books and websites giving the origin of names, but sometimes we can only make an educated guess at the meaning.

Comment: You explain that your name means 'calm disposition' in Sinhala. Do all names have clear meanings in your culture?

Comment: Yes. But since Sri Lanka was a Portuguese, Dutch and English colony some have names which have these influences.